# AskTimeoutException in logs of application.log

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework version 2.1.5 and I am getting AskTimeoutException on almost every web request.

The same code is deployed on staging server and there is no such issue.

```
{
Internal server error, for (GET) [/my/logout] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AskTimeoutException: Timed out]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Promise.scala:104) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:310) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.DefaultScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:193) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[scala-library.jar:na]

}
```

Comment: can you give a link to Play Framework version 2.1.5?

Comment: https://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.1.5/play-2.1.5.zip